# TYPO3 Crawler: get usefull error information when indexing external files

Tags: typo3

I have installed indexed_search and crawler in a TYPO3 6.0.2 system.

Being in "WEB > Info > Site Crawler > Crawler Log" I can start the indexing of a page containing links to files, and those Links are added to the queue (as explained in http://wiki.typo3.org/Crawler).

But when I click the read button in those newly added lines in order to start indexing of the files, I get an error message: "Error: No object: EXT:indexed_search/class.crawler..."

Chenging to "ADMIN TOOLS > Indexing > List External Documents" I can see that no external documents were indexed.

The files linked on that page are pdf files. pdfinfo and pdftotext are both installed in /usr/bin/ (and indexed_search is pointing to that location). Also this path is included in the open_basedir directive in apache's conf file for that particular website. I tried using pdftotext on the external file in a shell, and that worked.

Does anybody know how I could get a complete error message instead of that truncated one? I activated "Debug mode" in indexed_search's settings, but I am not sure where that debug information is written to.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Best regards

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think causes the problem:
In file /typo3/sysext/indexed_search/Classes/Indexer, lines 799 and 811, there is this call:

```
$crawler->addQueueEntry_callBack(0, $params, 'EXT:indexed_search/class.crawler.php:&TYPO3\\CMS\\IndexedSearch\\Controller\\SearchFormController_files', $this->conf['id']);
```

That Controller named SearchFormController_files does not exist. In the former version it was tx_indexedsearch_files, so I guess there is a typo in the current version.

I exchanged the above lines with…

```
$crawler->addQueueEntry_callBack(0, $params, 'EXT:indexed_search/class.crawler.php:&tx_indexedsearch_files', $this->conf['id']);
```

…and now I get an "OK" when I try to index a file.